# php include file does not include

Tags: php

I'm using eloquent orm independently(not in laravel).
In a higher level folder I tried:

```
include '../app/configdb.php';
```

Which does not work:
However if I use this:

```
$oldcwd = getcwd();
chdir("../");
include 'app/configdb.php';
chdir($oldcwd);
```

This works. This is only true of my eloquent initialization file.
Later in same file I:

```
require '../views/petlist.php';
```

And that works.
Any ideas why the ../ won't work? And I did try require instead of include.

Comment: Does it say that the file is not found or anything else? May be `configdb.php` needs the current dir to be set to the top by `chdir("../");` to include other files, while `include '../` does not do so and you stay in your original dir.

Comment: I had a similar issue not long ago and I solved like this `require __dir__ . '/../views/petlist.php';` maybe it will help you too.

Answer (score 0):

The configdb.php loads the eloquent orm stuff.
Contents of that file.  So yes from this file eloquent is requiring other stuff.

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
$capsule = new Capsule();
$capsule->addConnection([
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'pbackdate',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
]);
//added/
//use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
//use Illuminate\Container\Container;
//$capsule->setEventDispatcher(new Dispatcher(new Container));

//added
$capsule->setAsGlobal();
$capsule->bootEloquent();
```

Comment: Thanks for that link, but I tryed all that a few days ago. Seems only thing working is the chdir("../"); I will retry things from that page again in case I missed something.